# Create regular expression from Array of search terms ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

Is there a way / gem to create regular expressions with some basic search parameters.

e.g.

```
Search = ["\"German Shepherd\"","Collie","poodle", "Miniature Schnauzer"]
```

Such that the regexp will search (case insensitively) for:

> "German Shepherd" - exactly 
>   OR
>   "Collie"
>   OR
>   "poodle"
>   OR
>   "Miniature" AND "Schnauzer"

So in this case something like:

```
/German\ Shepherd|Collie|poodle|(?=.*Miniature)(?=.*Schnauzer).+/i
```

(Open to suggestions of better ways of doing the last bit...)

Comment: Other than the fact that you want to split Miniature and Schnauzer but not German and Shepherd something like this would work. `/#{search.join('|')}/i` but given that additional criteria the methodology would become a bit more complex. Can you add any other "special cases" that might need additional handling like this?

Comment: Yeah, I got that far. The reason I ask is that I realised it wasn't handling "Miniature Schnauzer" correctly...

Comment: Other special case would be exclusions. i.e. an additional array of exclusions that if they are present would invaidate the match,

Comment: e.g. -Chihuahua or -(Giant Poodle) or -"Belgian Shepherd" but I suspect that's a variant on the same with a separate array, inverted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the question properly, here you go:

```
regexps =  ["\"German Shepherd\"","Collie","poodle", "Miniature Schnauzer"]

# those in quotes
greedy = regexps.select { |re| re =~ /\A['"].*['"]\z/ } # c'"mon, parser
# the rest unquoted
non_greedy = (regexps - greedy).map(&:split).flatten

# concatenating...                     ⇓⇓⇓ get rid of quotes     
all = Regexp.union(non_greedy + greedy.map { |re| re[1...-1] })
#⇒ /Collie|poodle|Miniature|Schnauzer|German\ Shepherd/
```

**UPD**

I finally got what is to be done with `Miniature Schnauzer` (please see a comment below for further explanation.) That said, these words **are to be permuted and joined** with non-greedy `.*?`:

```
non_greedy = (regexps - greedy).map(&:split).map do |re|
  # single word? YES : NO, permute and join
  re.length < 2 ? re : re.permutation.map { |p| Regexp.new p.join('.*?') }     
end.flatten
all = Regexp.union(non_greedy + greedy.map { |re| re[1...-1] })

#=> /Collie|poodle|(?-mix:Miniature.*?Schnauzer)|(?-mix:Schnauzer.*?Miniature)|German\ Shepherd/
```

Comment: What the Miniature Schnauzer bit does is add a collection of words which must be found together, though not necessarily in that exact form, so "Miniature Black Schnauzer" would come back as a match as would "Schnauzer - Miniature"

Comment: Thanks, this is really good. (?=.*Miniature)(?=.*Schnauzer).+ I think is a slightly more elegant form (the .+ martches the whole thing, the others pick out the two words. Especially if there are more than two words.. Just trying to work out how to do that consisitently...

Comment: Possibly with a /b parameter to make sure it's matching whole words

Comment: Not sure if this is 100% correct because I am not 100% sure of the true parameters but this is an amazingly elegant solution to a less than straight forward problem. Although due to "poodle" I think it makes sense to add the `/i` flag so it also matches "Poodle". +1 either way because I love this solution and you managed to make it extremely concise for something that I would have ended up building a reasonable sized parser for.